# Understanding Classes (What to use them for)

Tags: php, class

I have a quick question regarding how to use classes. I am what I would call a beginner at programming and have set myself the task of creating a small web based game to learn. In the game I want to have various unit types (i.e. Swordsman, Cavalry, Archer). I have been told that I should create a separate class for each type of unit however I have also been told to create one class like "class unit". Which is the correct way to use classes? I apologise if this is vague but I can't think of a better way to word it. Having searched this site for other class related questions, they don't seem to cover this type of usage.

```
class unit {

$unitName = "";
$unitSpeed = "";
$unitHealth = "";
$unitDamage = "";

}
```

or

```
class archer {

$archerSpeed = "";
$archerHealth = "";
$archerDamage = "";

}

class cavalry {

$cavalrySpeed = "";
$cavalryHealth = "";
$cavalryDamage = "";

}
```

Comment: It largely depends on what you have to do and how far your code needs to go. For such a case, I would personally create a "unit" generic class expecting, in its `__construct()`, a string, defining the "unit type" and then I would **extend** the class according to what I have to implement. In a nutshell, you're supposed to use classes (and objects) to implement some "vague" things that may be slightly different between them, but that has many common parameters (like your case)

Comment: In your case, try to ask yourself this: "What is an archer going to do? and a cavarly unit?" most likely, both of them will have some health points, a description, an attack value, an attacking function and eventually some speed or something like that. In such a case, so, since they have MANY common parameters, a **class** named "units" is surely a must, and the next step is thinking about HOW you should implement that class ;) For an easier understanding I would personally recommend you to search for: 1) What is a class. 2) How to extend a class. 3) What is an interface.

Answer (score 2):

the better way i sto organize your code, like this:

```
abstract class Unit
{
    public $speed=0;
    public $health=0;
    public $damage=0;
}


class Archer extends Unit
{
}


class Wizard extents Unit
{
    public $mana;
}

class ArcherAdvanced extends Unit
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->health = 4; 
    }
}
```

With this structure You must always use a specific class, but implementing that can be very easy. It's also easy to add some property for different usage (like wizard).

U can use this in other class like this:

```
class Game
{
    public  function run()
    {
        $gandalf = new Wizard();
        $legolas = new Archer();
        // then fight!!
    }

}
```

I hope this can be helpful. However i suggest to take a look here: http://www.phptherightway.com/

In the class ArcherAdvanced , when you use it, and do new ArcherAdvanced(), yuou automatically set health to value = 4.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This makes sense. So let's say I want the class Archer to have a different value for health, would I just include it like this?

class Archer extends Unit
{
public $health=4;
}

Comment: @AlexW: Actually you will need to call a function (like a constructor) and, since Archer is extending Unit, it already has a "$health" property, therefore you can override it by doing: `$this->health = 4;` . Using an ` abstract class` is a pretty good approach, but it is also quite advanced, if you're new to OOP in php, you would better start by using a basic class first :P

Comment: I do a little update i hope it clearify your question

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you want would be to use subclasses. See here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

You would make a base class called "unit" that would contain all of the information that is common between all types of units.

Then you would make a class for each type of unit that contains any logic that makes this type of unit different from the others.

With this approach, you are being "DRY" by not repeating code that is common for all units (which would probably happen with 3 different classes), and yet flexible in case there are differences between them whose code belongs in the class file (Where using only one "unit" class you might have to use conditionals to accomplish the same thing).

Here is what the base code might look like:

```
class Unit {
//Defaults for all units
$unitName = ""; 
$unitSpeed = "1";
$unitHealth = "1";
$unitDamage = "1";

}

class Archer extends Unit{

$unitName = "archer";

}

class Cavalry extends Unit {

$unitName = "cavalry";

}
```